# Blender crashes when I add HDRI

Tags: rendering, gpu, hdri

So I have been using Blender for a couple months now and I'm working on a "big" project but blender keeps crashing when I add a HDRI and render cycles on my GPU.
These are my PC specs:
AMD ryzen 7 3700X
Nvidia GTX 1660 Ti

Is there a fix or am I doing something wrong? The HDRI is 927Mb.

Comment: Sounds like you are running out of GPU memory